# Transformations of stationary processes - counterexample?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I am looking at a theorem about transformations of stationary processes that reads:

If $(e_t)_t$ is a strictly stationary process, and $x_t=f(e_t,e_{t-1},e_{t-2},...) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is a random vector, then $(x_t)_t$ is a strictly stationary process.

It is emphasized  in the main text that the transformation can include the full history of $e_t$

Counterexample: Suppose $(e_t)_t$ is some i.i.d. process (strictly stationary by design) and the proposed transformation is $x_t=\sum_{j=0}^t e_j$

$x_t$ is absolutely not a strictly stationary process?

How can both be true at the same time?

Thanks